# Access Form_Current() Event works only when pressing F5

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Here is the code:

```
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

With cn
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=KalkDB_V1;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx"
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open
End With

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

With cmd
    Set .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "qspSuperliste_Update"
    .Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
End With
```

I have a Subform. It's source i a linked SQL Server Table. Select * From Linked Table. The subform is only a datashett view. If the user is changing a explicite column then the table have to be updated. And this should work, when the user jump to the next row. But it doesn' work. Nothing is happend. But when i jump to the next row and press F5 then it works. That mean the Storend Procedure will be executed and the table is updated. But why does it only work with pressing F5??? And when i write a .Requery in the code, it works, BUT then the requery does take 5 seconds!!! When pressing F5 it's faster than Flash ;-)

How have an idea!?

THX

Greetz Vegeta_77

P.S.
In the Form.Current are two other call's for example and they work without F5 and without a requery.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i know it better!!! The solution is:
Wrongly I was thinking:

Pressing F5 = Form.Requery

But that's wrong. Right is:

Pressing F5 = Form.Refresh

The last record will be refreshed by using the .Refresh.

Also you should know, that I was trying to use DoCmd.RefreshRecord, but this is the most slowest, what I was trying!!! It takes more than the double time!!!

Greetz
Vegeta_77